# Allow other files to be uploaded after FileSizeLimitExceededException for just one file

Tags: spring-boot, exception, multifile-uploader

I have setup an application server using springboot which allows upload of multiple files.
I have configured the application.properties using the following:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
```

When running a request using postman, 
I am uploading 3 files under the key called "files"
[image: Postman FORM DATA]

```
File-1 is 11MB
File-2 is 1MB
File-3 is 1MB
```

The request fails with the following error:

```
"message": "Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field files exceeds its maximum permitted size of 10485760 bytes."
```

I understand this is from providing size limits for the server.
But Is there a way to handle the exception such that only 1 file is excluded from upload, and the others are allowed.

Tried with exception handler to fetch request.
But this handler is applied to the overall request causing all the files to be skipped.

```
@PostMapping("/file-upload-service/file-uploader")
public List<UploadFileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam String destination, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws FileStorageException {
        logger.info("Uploading multiple files...");
        Date uploadDate = new Date();
        logger.info("Upload operation started at {}", uploadDate);
        return Arrays.asList(files)
                .stream()
                .map(file -> uploadFile(destination, file))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```